# Html call function with input value

Tags: javascript, html, button, input, onclick

is there a trick in html to call JS function() with the input value, like here :

example: here I want to call show_name( with the input[user_name] value )

Note: I don't wanna use JS

```
<form>
    <label>Enter your name :</label>
    <input type='text' name='user_name'>    
    <button type='submit' onclick='show_name( [want to get input value here] )' >Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Your question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40134104/how-to-pass-the-button-value-into-my-onclick-event-function)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass the button value into my onclick event function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40134104/how-to-pass-the-button-value-into-my-onclick-event-function)

Comment: _"Note: I don't wanna use JS"_ Why not? And how do you expect to call a JS function without JS?

Comment: @PedroBarroso    thkx but (this) didnt make it because I have to call the function with a button not the input itself

Comment: @Klaycon unfortunately no

Comment: @j08691 to avoid name space saturation i have many js included with lot of html ids so you can easily affect the same id to 2 tag and here start problems :)

Comment: @Mr.freelance indeed, it doesn't fit your exact question - here, I googled it to find a better fit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427041/javascript-passing-text-input-to-a-onclick-handler

Comment: @Klaycon this solve my problem thanks